# Can't make Knockout.js' recommended AMD module pattern to work

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-3.0

I'm trying to make Knockout's recommended AMD module pattern to work in a sample project but the template (.html) file doesn't get loaded. It is searched by Require.js in a different directory. The pattern I am reffering to is this:

[A recommended AMD module pattern](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html#a-recommended-amd-module-pattern)

where the viewModel and the template are returned by the js component part.

Here is my Require.js config:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        jquery: "jquery-2.1.4.min",
        ko: "knockout-3.3.0",
        "jquery.vertmenusc": "plugins/jquery.vertmenusc/jquery.vertmenusc"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery.vertmenusc": ["jquery"]
    }
});

require(['jquery', 'ko', 'jquery.vertmenusc'], function($, ko) {

    ko.components.register('vert-menu', {
        require: "../templates/vert-menu/vert-menu"
    });

    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

And here is the component's js part (vert-menu.js). The template is just basic HTML:

```
define(['ko', 'text!./vert-menu.html'], function(ko, template) {

    function VertMenuViewModel() {
    }

    return { viewModel: VertMenuViewModel, template: template };
});
```

My directory structure is like this:

```
root
  + js
  + plugins
  + jquery.vertmenusc
    - jquery.vertmenusc.css
    - jquery.vertmenusc.js
  - jquery-2.1.4.min.js
  - knockout-3.3.0.js
  - main.js
  - require.min.js
  - text.js
  + template
    +vert-menu
      - vert-menu.html
      - vert-menu.js
  - index.html
```

And the error I am getting:

```
http://localhost:8080/templates/templates/templates/vert-menu/vert-menu.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is Require.js looking at that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `require.config` add a path for templates

```
...
paths: {
    templates: "../templates",
    ...
```

Then when you register the component use this

```
ko.components.register('vert-menu', {
    require: "templates/vert-menu/vert-menu"
});
```

instead of `../templates`